# Вопрос по парсингу JSON файла android

Tags: android, json

Читал официальную документацию, поиск по ключу/значению нашел, а вот метода, который бы проверял существует объект или нет не нашел. 
Другими словами, как проверить есть ли в файле объект `"lada_car"` или нет, json файл:

```
{"lada_car":{"type":"седан","model":"Kalina","manufacturer":"Lada"},"toyota_car":{"type":"седан","model":"Camry","manufacturer":"Toyota"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

JsonObject имеет свойство `has`

Пример: `JsonObject(result).has(lada_car)`

Где `result` - ваш json в формате `String`

Comment: метод has — проверяет, содержит ли объект указанный ключ. А мне нужно проверить, существует ли этот объект или нет без выброса исключения.